# Cannot create page method "GetCompletionList" because not code behind or code file is found

Tags: c#-4.0

I can't get AJAX CT Autocomplete to work. The problem is when I start writing in textbox nothing happens. The first problem I had experienced was when I tried to Add AutoComplete page method I got an error: "Cannot create page method "GetCompletionList"...". Then I tried creating it manually, but still nothing happens.